Is There a benefit in Defining Sequences on Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ Beyond $\mathbb{N}$?
In introductory real analysis, we typically define sequences as functions from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. However, I'm intrigued by the possibility of generalizing the set we use, instead of relying exclusively on $\mathbb{N}$. For example, we could consider sequences defined on sets like $2\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{N}/2$.
My intuition suggests that the key properties we rely on with $\mathbb{N}$ are that it is bounded below and unbounded above. Wouldn't it be more insightful if we considered functions from a general set $A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded below but not bounded above?
For example, the definition of convergence could be rephrased as follows:
A function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded below and unbounded above, is said to converge to $L$, if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $M \in R$ such that $\forall x\in A$ where $x \geq M$, we get $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.
Remarkably, many properties of limits of sequences remain intact in this more general setting. For instance:
The limit remains unique.
We still have the algebraic limit theorem, squeeze theorem, monotone convergence theorem, Cauchy criterion, and order limit theorem.
The Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem also seems to hold.
There are, however, some subtle differences. For example, while a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded, in this new framework, a convergent function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ would only be eventually bounded. Furthermore, this generalization may extend naturally to functional limits with minimal modification.
Would this generalization of sequences be useful or insightful in understanding limits? Or is there something unique about sequences defined on $\mathbb{N}$ that makes this approach less effective?

Yes, there are "sequences" which don't have domain of $\mathbb N$. For example, in set theory, it is common to study transfinite sequences, which typically have domains which are "longer" than $\mathbb N$. But it seems silly to change the domain from $\mathbb N$ to $2\mathbb N$, since these two sets are "the same" – more precisely, they are order-isomorphic under their standard orderings.

(By the way, if your "sequences" are allowed to have any domain whatsoever, then you are essentially just rehashing the definition of a function.)

@Joe This is exactly my point. Why use sequences instead of functions?

@abc1455 why use integers instead of reals in arithmetic ? Why not use complex numbers to count apples ? Sequences are an interesting object of study because their domain is countable; they ARE functions, just specific functions (just like an integer is a complex number). And usually constraining definitions make them easier to manipulate.

You might also be interested in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)

Since $\mathbb N$ is a simpler object than a subset of $\mathbb R$ which is bounded below and unbounded above, I'm not seeing any reason why I would want to work with the latter. To convince me, I think you would need to give an example of this approach where things are better than if we work with ordinary sequences. But I suspect that many of the times where you think your sequences would do a better job, this is just where using general functions is appropriate and natural.

sequences are intuitive and natural but there are limitations even when we talk about countable indexing sets - a very common situation is if $a_n, n \in \mathbb Z$ is given, what is the meaning of $\sum_n a_n$ and there are various definitions (Cauchy limit, unrestricted limit) though the most general which applies to any indexing set $I$ uses nets; similarly if we work in nonmetrizable spaces where sequential convergence is not equivalent to convergence, nets are needed; so in brief we use sequences because they are intuitive but occasionally we need generalizations like nets

I think the simple answer is that sequences are used when a domain of $\mathbb{N}$ a sufficient tool for the job. If you want to use some other more complicated set as the domain, the question is “why?” What does that more complicated domain set accomplish?
